# Rails: Application.html.erb suddently stopped rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was doing something completely different with my app, when suddently my application.html.erb stopped rendering in my views. I even took back all the changes I had made and that did not fix the problem. What can have happened? I've searched everywhere and tried different things, nothing works. Everything else works fine. Here are the files with the changes.

**application_controller**

```
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
    # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception
    helper_method :current_user


    def initialize(attributes = {})
       @name = attributes[:name]
       @email = attributes[:email]
    end

    def createRound
        @gamerounds = Gameround.all
        @gameround = Gameround.new({endtime: 'John Appleseed', active: true})

        respond_to do |format|
          if @gameround.save
            format.html { redirect_to @gameround, notice: 'Gameround was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @gameround }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @gameround.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
     end

    private

    def current_user
        @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
    end

    def admin_user
        @admin_user = User.find_by(username: 'Admin')
    end

    protected 
    def authenticate_user
      if session[:user_id]
         # set current user object to @current_user object variable
        @current_user = User.find session[:user_id] 
        return true 
      else
        redirect_to(:controller => 'sessions', :action => 'login')
        return false
      end
    end
    def save_login_state
      if session[:user_id]
        redirect_to(:controller => 'sessions', :action => 'profile')
        return false
      else
        return true
      end
    end
 end
```

**game_session controller**

```
  class GamesessionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_gamesession, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :authenticate_user, :except => [:index, :show, :new ]
  layout :application

  # GET /gamesessions
  # GET /gamesessions.json
  def index
    @gamesessions = Gamesession.all
  end

  # GET /gamesessions/1
  # GET /gamesessions/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /gamesessions/new
  def new
    @gamesession = Gamesession.new

    unless !session[:user_id]
      if !current_user.admin?
        redirect_to '/play'
      end
    end
  end

  # GET /gamesessions/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /gamesessions
  # POST /gamesessions.json
  def create
    Gamesession.delete_all

    @gamesession = Gamesession.new(gamesession_params)

    createRound

  end

  # PATCH/PUT /gamesessions/1
  # PATCH/PUT /gamesessions/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @gamesession.update(gamesession_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @gamesession, notice: 'Gamesession was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @gamesession }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @gamesession.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /gamesessions/1
  # DELETE /gamesessions/1.json
  def destroy
    @gamesession.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to gamesessions_url, notice: 'Gamesession was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_gamesession
      @gamesession = Gamesession.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def gamesession_params

      params.require(:gamesession).permit(:players, :flares, :aliens, :gamesetup, expansion:[], level:[])


    end
end
```

**config.routes**

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do


  resources :gamerounds do 
    resources :currentplayers
  end 
  resources :gamesessions
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

 # Artikkel, Alien liste
  resources :expansions do
    resources :aliens
  end

  resources :users



  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'gamesessions#new'
  get "signup", :to => "users#new"
  get "login", :to => "sessions#login"
  post "login_attempt", :to => "sessions#login_attempt"
  get "logout", :to => "sessions#logout"
  get "profile", :to => "sessions#profile"
  get "setting", :to => "sessions#setting"
  get "play", :to => "gamesessions#index"

  get "aliens", :to => "aliens#index"


  #match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'

  # Example of regular route:
  #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

  # Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
  #   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

  # Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Example resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', on: :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with concerns:
  #   concern :toggleable do
  #     post 'toggle'
  #   end
  #   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
  #   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

  # Example resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end
end
```

Comment: Where is the application.html.erb file? And what were you doing leading up to this?

Comment: *took back all the changes*, that doesn't sound like you are using git?

Comment: I'm using git, but I was just really bad at commiting while I was working. So I had done alot of other changes that were working fine before this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are defining the `initialize` method in your controller without calling `super`.

```
def initialize(attributes = {})
   @name = attributes[:name]
   @email = attributes[:email]
   super
end
```

Comment: in a controller, I think the `initialize` should be removed altogether.

Comment: @ThomasR.Koll +1, I agree

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked! I'm testing rails for the first time.